# How can I get Scroll Offset Y value with Animated.event in React Native?

Tags: react-native

How can I get Scroll Offset Y value with `Animated.event` in React Native? When `useNativeDriver: false` the code works properly. However, when `useNativeDriver: true` it outputs `0`. I need to use `useNativeDriver: true`.

[Snack Expo Dev Link](https://snack.expo.dev/-r8o_E8q50biSIVKBCgRi)

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button,
  Animated
} from 'react-native';

const DATA = [{id: 0},{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4},{id: 5},{id: 6},{id: 7},{id: 8},{id: 9}];

const Item = ({title}) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {

    const contentOffsetY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    const onScroll = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: contentOffsetY } } }], { useNativeDriver: false });

    function getY(){
      console.log(contentOffsetY._value)
    }

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>

      <Button title="get Y" onPress={getY}/>

      <Animated.FlatList
        onScroll={onScroll}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Item title={item.id} />}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>

  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16,
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

[When using Native Animated it's not available everywhere.](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2017/02/14/using-native-driver-for-animated#caveats)

It is changing contentOffsetY but will not show in console.log from Component body.

You could see the side effects by adding the animated value to another view:

```
const App = () => {    
  const contentOffsetY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const onScroll = Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: contentOffsetY } } }],
    { useNativeDriver: true }
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>    
      <Animated.FlatList
        // ...flatList props
      />

      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles.testViewAbs,
          {
            transform: [{ translateY: contentOffsetY }],
          },
        ]}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  testViewAbs: {
    position: "absolute",
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    height: 50,
    width: 50,
    backgroundColor: "blue",
  },
});
```

Or You can add an extra ref or state if you want to use it somewhere other than native:

```
 const contentOffsetYRef = useRef(0);

  const onScroll = Animated.event(
    [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: contentOffsetY } } }],
    {
      listener: ({ nativeEvent: { contentOffset:{ y } } }) => {
        contentOffsetYRef.current = y;
      },
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }
  );

  function getY() {
    console.log(contentOffsetYRef.current);
  }
```

Comment: Can I get the current value when I touch the button instead of constantly listening with Listener?

Comment: You can add an extra ref or state in listener if you want to use it somewhere other than native. _I have added a sample code to the end of my answer_.

Comment: Yes, it works as I want now. If there is no better solution, I will give the bounty :)